# get url after http:// from complete url string using php

Tags: php, string

i am storing url string in database like this,

```
'http://www.domain.com'
```

how can i display above string like

'www.domain.com'

**I need regular expression in first hand**

Comment: *“I need regular expression”* – No, you don’t.

Comment: now i have edited the question, **i need regular expression** would that help poke mate ?

Comment: *Why* do you think you need a regular expression? From what you want you absolutely do not need one, so please tell us *why*.

Comment: because i dont know how to form regular expression and i am working on it, i can manipulate string quite well, i dont know how to use regular expression and i dont have MUCH TIME TO READ LONG MANUALS FOR THAT,

Comment: So you want this to learn regular expressions? Then you should really pick a task that actually requires regular expressions because otherwise it will not really differ from a normal `str_replace` (or similar) use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can use 
$url = 'http://www.domain.com';

`str_replace('http://', '', $url);`

it will return exactly `www.domain.com`

Answer (score 4):

with [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) you can split a url into it's parts and get the ones you want to. in your case (looking for the `host`), it would be:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com';
$parts = parse_url($url);
$result = $parts['host'];
```

this has a big advantage over the other posted solutions: it's ready to go with https-urls, urls with get-parameters and/or url's including htaccess-authentication paramneters without having to change the code.

Comment: i did it and it's giving me `[scehem]` and `[host]` and i can display `[host] here [host] = www.domain.com`

i am actually looking for a regular expresion

Comment: in your question you're writng that "www.domain.com" is exactly what you're looking for. maybe you should give some more examples.

Comment: yeah i am exactly looking for same, but more with regular expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below:

```
<?php
str_replace('http://', '', $url);
```

Edit:

Since you insist on regex solution, here's one that takes care of http and https in one

```
echo preg_replace( '/^(htt|ht|tt)p\:?\/\//i', '', $url);
```

Comment: what happens if someone enters an https-url? i know this wasn't directly part of the question, but you should at least give a hint you code will fail in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo substr('http://www.domain.com',7);

if (substr('http://www.domain.com',7) == 'http://' or substr('https://www.domain.com',8) == 'https://')
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that problem. I actually double checked the value too :D

Comment: what happens if someone enters an https-url? i know this wasn't directly part of the question, but you should at least give a hint you code will fail in that case.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution for modifying strings without parsing the URL (i.e. you should learn to be able to do something like this yourself):

```
if (stripos($url, 'http://', 0) == 0)
    $url = substr($url, 7);
```

You also could easily add another check for a `https://` prefix or whatever else:

```
if (stripos($url, 'https://', 0) == 0)
    $url = substr($url, 8);
```

With a regular expression, albeit completely unnecessary as there is nothing that requires one, you could to it like this:

```
$url = preg_replace('/^http:\\/\\//', '', $url);
```

Or with direct support for https:

```
$url = preg_replace('/^https?:\\/\\//', '', $url);
```